# The Apple ID does not match the one associated with the order

Tags: mac, apple-id, apple-store, applecare

I completed an EDU order for a new Mac this morning. The order doesn’t show in my AppleID, but I got the confirmation email from Apple to the email address provided during the order (paid with ApplePay). That address is equal to that of my AppleID.
When logging into my account from the Order Status page, I get the “The Apple ID does not match the one associated with the order”. If I then try to look for this order without logging in, and provide that same email address, it shows “The order is already associated to another AppleID”.
I spent 3h today on the phone with Apple Support. I believe I’m now acquainted with every advisor from their Greece office (I’m based in Italy), yet they couldn’t help. They bounced me from one department to another, some of them feeling sure the technical support should’ve been able to align the order and the AppleID, others bouncing me back to post-sale since only they could help.
In the end, all I got was a “don’t worry, Sir… it will be all right”. That’s the best I could get from them. No one was able to solve this.
There are several topics about this on discussions.apple.com but none of the solutions proposed there has any effect. There is no “Add to AppleID” button in my order.
Does anyone here have a solution that works?

Comment: The Apple ID you use with a computer doesn’t need to be the one for purchase, so this is totally normal. What is the concern or issue you need fixed? Can you edit this to spell out something specific. Are you concerned it won’t be attached to your proper ID once it arrives? Do you need help tracking the order? Something else entirely?

Comment: I have no other Apple ID. From the link in the email I’ve received I can see the order status but not edit (e.g., I can’t cancel the order if I wanted to, nor edit any detail). The Safari tab that opens from the link is titled “Guest Order”; from Apple Support articles I should see “Add to Apple ID”, but I don’t. Above the green bar there is a “Log In” blue button to manage the order. Once I login with the only Apple ID I have it tells me to login with the ID used for the purchase. This doesn’t make sense to me, nor apparently it does to Apple Support so far.

Comment: I would like to track it in my Apple ID and be able to edit the order, since I’m the purchaser, yet I’m given no option whatsoever. This is not normal.